# Can you please help identify this circular part with 2 black wires and 2 red wires?

Tags: identification, components

I found this part in an old auction lot I bought.  Could you please help identify what this part is?

[image: photo 1 of component]

[image: photo 2 of component]

Comment: Looks like a piezoelectric disk

Comment: Could be an inductor or transformer.  Have you made any resistance measurements on the leads?

Comment: Looks pretty ancient (1988) measure the resistance, I was thinking of this ,  yet it’s not piezo with thick leads yet has an air hole https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/pui-audio-inc/AT-1750-TFL-LW95-R/1532059. CM choke sounds right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly a toroidal common-mode choke in a plastic case.

Especially if it's relatively dense (ferrite core) and if red-to-red and black-to-black measure short and red to black measures open.

Comment: Your description matches exactly the characteristics of this part. It is definitely a toroidal common-mode choke in a plastic case.   Thank you very much.